# {{$state.current.noMenu ? $state.current.title : titles[$state.current.type]}} Error when trying to run Magento 2 setup

Tags: magento2

I am installing Magento 2 and getting the following error when trying to run the setup. What am I missing?

{{$state.current.noMenu ? $state.current.title : titles[$state.current.type]}}

Comment: Have you find any solution for this question ?

Comment: Any Solutions about that problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have received this even on Magento 2.3.  Two things I have seen that cause this:

1. Running magento in a multi-docker/container environment where all the containers aren't synced up in terms of magento files.
2. Possibly some type of browser caching issue.  The last time it happened, I opened the same site in an incognito window and the site loaded up properly.